# The PHP form action is located on another page! how to validate the form and show the error message on the view page?

Tags: php, html

I have two files, the first one is for displaying a form(HTML), and the second one is for the form action(PHP Code). I made a simple validation code but it shows me an error message like the image below.

[image]

**view.php**

```
<form action="redirect.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" />
<span style="color: red;"><?php echo $nameError;?></span>

<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**redirect.php**

```
<?php

require "db.php";

// Initialize variables to null.
$nameError ="";

// On submitting form below function will execute.
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    
    if(empty($name)) {
        $nameError = "Name is required";
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Why not validate form input with Javascript first—save a trip to the server?

Comment: because I have a task to validated with php

Comment: Best to validate on both client and server. I don't see why @adam-p 's server-side PHP validation answer doesn't work for you. I like #1 best—simplest and least round trips to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Because you defined the **nameError** variable in the **redirect.php** but you want to use it in **view.php**.

There are several solutions:

**1:** Move your validation code to the top of **view.php**.

**2:** Pass the **nameError** content into `$_SESSION` global array. e.g.: `$_SESSION['nameError'] = "Name is required";` And modify validation to `

```
if(empty($name)) {
    $_SESSION['nameError'] = "Name is required";
    header("Location: view.php");
    exit;
}`
```

And change code in **view.php** from `<span style="color: red;"><?php echo $nameError;?></span>`   to

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['nameError'])): ?>
<span style="color: red;"><?php echo $_SESSION['nameError'];?></span>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I change it now but it still not show up ?